# How to turn off the beep only in bash tab-complete

Tags: bash, terminal, autocomplete, bell

I find the beep useful for some things, so I **only** want to turn it off for tab completion (I'm not asking how to completely turn it off, that [has already been answered](https://serverfault.com/q/26405/133416) in a different question on Serverfault). I also don't have root access, working on RHEL5.

Answer (score 104):

Readline library has `bell-style` variable:

> Controls what happens when Readline wants to ring the terminal bell.
> If set to ‘none’, Readline never rings the bell. If set to ‘visible’,
> Readline uses a visible bell if one is available. If set to ‘audible’
> (the default), Readline attempts to ring the terminal’s bell.

So you can put into your `~/.inputrc` file following line:

```
 set bell-style none
```

Next, run `bind -f ~/.inputrc` once to load it.

Comment: If you want this setup to be default for all users of the system, you can edit /etc/inputrc config file with root user.

Comment: then run `bind -f ~/.inputrc` to reload it.

Comment: Thank you, SO much!! I was nearing the point of projectile reconfiguration of my system (throwing my laptop across the room).

Answer (score 30):

If you don't want to create and maintain a separate `~/.inputrc` file, you can also just add this line to `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
bind 'set bell-style none'
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc` to reload it.

Comment: This is the ONLY solution that worked for me (although "visible" option doesn't work).  Even disabling Critical Stop and Default Beep Windows sounds didn't work (using WSL in ConEmu).

Answer (score 17):

I'm not aware of any way to disable the tab completion bell in `bash` (aside from disabling the bell entirely or changing it to the subjectively-more-annoying visual bell).

You could try `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` in your `~/.inputrc` - this makes the shell show the list of matching commands/items immediately when you hit <kbd>tab</kbd> instead of waiting for you to hit <kbd>tab</kbd> twice.
A side effect is that there is no bell before the candidate matches are shown.

Answer (score 8):

In ~/.inputrc, there exists the following possibility, but it didn't do anything for me. It just rings the bell. This may be a bug in the Cygwin bash.

```
set bell-style visible
```